# How many days does it take for a frenuloplasty on the penis to heal?

Tags: sex, penis, self-healing-repairing, fertility

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenuloplasty_of_prepuce_of_penis) says:

> Under normal circumstances the incision heals completely in around
> **six to eight weeks**, after which time normal sexual activity can
> resume.

Here pdf from [Daycase UK](https://yeovilhospital.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Frenuloplasty-17-09-2020.pdf) says:

> You can get back to normal activities within **2-3 weeks**.

Comment: The Daycase link apparently doesn't consider sexual activity "normal activities" because they give 2-3 weeks for normal activities and 4 weeks for sexual activities. The wikipedia article doesn't cite a source for _the author's opinion_ that  6-8 weeks is required. I would take the advice of the surgeon who performed (or is going to perform) the procedure. If you're just investigating the procedure then I would consider the advice of a credible web site like Daycase, but I would completely ignore the opinion of some anonymous wikipedia editor who cites nothing to support their _opinion_.